# Can you use a fieldset in Sencha Touch for displaying data?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

This is for displaying contact details in an addressbook application.

I am getting a json result set and I would like to display this data nicely formatted in a fieldset.

Is there a way to do that easily? or must I copy the full html output from a fieldset and put it inside a itemTpl such as it appears in the examples (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/forms/index.html)
E.g.

```
<div class="x-inner x-form-inner x-translatable x-scroll-scroller" id="ext-element-6">
<div class="x-container x-form-fieldset" id="ext-fieldset-1">
    <div class="x-docking-vertical">
        <div id="ext-title-1" class="x-form-fieldset-title x-docked-top">
            <div class="x-innerhtml " id="ext-element-97">Personal Info</div>
        </div>
        <div class="x-body" id="ext-element-98">
            <div class="x-inner x-form-fieldset-inner" id="ext-element-8">
                <div class="x-container x-field-text x-field x-label-align-left x-field-required x-field-labeled x-field-clearable x-form-label-nowrap" id="ext-textfield-1">
                    <div class="x-form-label" id="ext-element-10" style="width: 40% !important; "><span id="ext-element-11">Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x-component-outer" id="ext-element-9">
                        <div id="ext-input-1" class="x-field-input">
                            <input id="ext-element-12" class="x-input-el x-form-field x-input-text" type="text" name="name" autocapitalize="off" value="{Name}">
                            <div class="x-clear-icon" id="ext-element-14"></div>
                            <div class="x-field-mask" id="ext-element-13" style="display: none !important; "></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

etc...

Is there a simpler way? 
Thanks

Comment: post the code for view that is having form and json you're having. are there any store, model ? Post that too. It's difficult to tell if we don't know what kinda of form and json your are having.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use a field set but have the fields set to readonly?

Comment: This is what I first thought of. But how do I do that? In ExtJS is easy, but as a result of a Dataview?